# tlmgr does not recognize xzdec

Tags: packages, installing, tlmgr

When trying `tlmgr init-usertree`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
```

So apparently, the program `xzdec` is not found. I downloaded, compiled and installed `xzdec` inside `~/.local`, but `tlmgr` still complains. The command `xzdec` works though. How can I make `tlmgr` aware of this installation?

Unfortunately, this is my work PC, so I don't have root access, and cannot simply

```
sudo apt-install xzdec
```

Comment: Which exact latex installation is installed here? It looks like linux. Is this texlive coming from the list dist? I use the upstream TeXLive and there is no xzdec on my computer. Probably because I already have `xz`

Comment: @daleif This is TexLive 2017/Debian, on Ubuntu 18.04, probably installed from the Ubuntu repositories. I also already have `xz` preinstalled, I don't know why `tlmgr` wants `xzdec`.

Comment: No idea, I generally do not recommend using the LaTeX from Ubuntu as it is often out of date, plus they change tlmgr (at least slightly). Installing upstream TeXLive 2019 does not require root access.